# Is it possible to link 2 different servers together?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am currently working on my new server and I want to link 2(or more) servers together. So I can have different gamemode on different servers. I would run 2(or more) server console at the same time so that player can join another server with executing a command. And for some reason, Multiverse and Multiworld plugin just won't work on my spigot server. Is there anyway possible that I can do this(Some people tell me before that this is possible, but they didn't tell me how.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to take a look at [BungeeCord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/about-bungeecord/).

> It acts as a proxy between the player's client and the connected Minecraft servers.
>   [..] free, easy, and reliable way to connect multiple Minecraft servers together

[BungeeCord latest build](http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeCord/)