# How to host a minecraft server with minigames for a LAN party?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to setup a small LAN party for my son and his friends. They really want the Hipixel / Mineplex experience but I'm not sure  if my internet connection will support them all playing online at the same time. Is it possible to setup a similar experience with a local server? 
I'm not worried about the networking, more the server setup. I assume the process is create a server, install some custom maps, but is there more to it than that? What custom minigame maps are available?

Can anyone point me to any guides?

Comment: You might be able to replicate some minigames with command blocks, just FYI. So a vanilla server/LAN world..

Answer (score 1):

Hypixel use only vanilla features to make his maps, so you won't need anything particular (plugins/mods) to make a server running these maps.

You can find the available for download Hypixel's maps [**here**](https://hypixel.net/downloads/)

I'd suggest you go for PvP or Fun maps (you can see the category below the map's name) rather than Adventure, cause these are aimed most of the time for multiplayer.

The map install itself is really simple, after downloading the map archive just unzip it into your server directory and change this line in server.properties like that :

```
level-name = theMapFolderName
```

Some maps may need specifics versions of minecraft so you want to make sure your minecraft server is matching this right version.

Also don't forget that Hypixel use command blocks to make such maps working so make sure you have set this property to your server.properties

```
enable-command-block=true
```

Btw [TeamFortress2 Map](https://hypixel.net/downloads/team-fortress-2-in-minecraft-2fort.24/) sounds fun

Comment: Great answer thank you, I'll accept it if nothing else comes along. Do you have any idea how to setup the 'lobby' and randomly select maps? This isn't really necessary but would be nice,

Comment: In the particular case you want to make a lobby , you have to install plugins cause that's not a vanilla server feature, so you need to use a Spigot Server for example rather than a vanilla one.
I recently answered a question about [how to link 2 minecraftservers together](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266872/is-it-possible-to-link-2-different-servers-together/266873#266873) so you may want to take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

RAM is an important part of running a server. Allowing different amounts of RAM can and do, depend on how many players you decide you have and how many plugins you have installed. You can allow more ram by editing this line:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar nogui
```

Simply just change the 1024 to a higher amount.

WARNING! Do not allow more RAM than is installed on your computer. You can check out how much RAM you have by going into settings, then clicking system, the go all the way down on the left side bar and click About. There should be a line of text saying:

> Installed RAM:   (Amount of RAM)GB

A lot of people recommend using only allowing half of your installed RAM to your server. If you really need more RAM, the most I would recommend would be 3/4 of your installed RAM. 1GB = 1024 MB.

Answer (score 0):

As Pronox mentioned, you can setup a normal minecraft server. If you want more you woul'd have to install a bukkit / spigot server and install plugins:

Spigot installation:
https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/

Plugins:
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/categories/bukkit.4/
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/

Thera a cool plugins to creat paintball maps or everything else. If you want to go advanced you can develop your own ones with java:

https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-plugin-development/

What you can do with plugins:

- Minigames
- Multiple worlds
- New game mechanics

There are also a lot of videos covering these topics.

Answer (score 0):

If i would answer the question in the title:

> How to host a minecraft server with minigames for a LAN party?

I would recommend to just do a vanilla server with a world or if you would not want to waste time to setup all of this, just download the world and paste it into the saves folder and then Open To Lan.

**Server Setup**

You can find the download of the official vanilla server & a small tutorial how to do it here: https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server

> Please note: This server setup is only compatible with Minecraft for
>   PC/Mac.
>
> If you want to run a Minecraft multiplayer server by yourself things
>   get kind of involved (see this wiki article for a tutorial). First
>   make sure you can use java from the command line. On Linux and macOS
>   this should already be set up but on Windows you might have to tinker
>   with the PATH environment variable.
>
> Download minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar and run it with the following
>   command:
>
> java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar nogui
>
> Should you want to start the server with it's graphical user interface
>   you can leave out the "nogui" part.

To deal with the command `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.11.2.jar nogui` just use create a .bat file and just add the line into the text document/bat file.

If you really want to take it to the next step and create server that have all the plugins and stuff, it would take a long time and you have to do extra work for nothing. 
(I would not recommend this if it is only for LAN)

**Importing Minigame to server**

Now to import a minigame to the server you just need to download a .zip that contains files for the minecraft world.

After you have downloaded the .zip file and now you can open it and drag the FOLDER that it is inside the zip file. If there is no files in the zip folder but another folder inside it, drag that one instead. (that contains files and folders). Drag it into the Server Folder and rename the folder to `world`.

Now you got your local server setup for minigames.

Answer (score -1):

I would actually recommend Realms. If you haven't already actually used up your free trial, you can set it up to have different minigames etc.

Comment: I would not recommend that just for a local party, having your own FREE minecraft server for a small amount of time. Its easy to setup your own server.