# How can I connect users to another server on Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to start a Java Edition server, and I am having trouble connecting users to another server. I know that the `/connect` command exists, but I was just wondering if there's an alternative for Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to link 2 different servers together?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266872/is-it-possible-to-link-2-different-servers-together)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to a BungeeCord server which is a bit of an undertaking to setup. Most minigame / servers with a "hub" use BungeeCord as it allows much more players to be online consecutively- the trick? they are all connected to different servers which are then connected to each other using the bungeecord software.
[This is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJSJvmKReEc) a pretty good tutorial, but be advised it was created by a server host- although the instructions are pretty universal and can be adapted to any host you use.