# How do I send players between servers in Minecraft java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have two 1.19 Minecraft java servers running on an Ubuntu machine. From in game, how would I send a player from server A, to server B? It needs to be something that both a command block could run, and also a player.

I've searched around, but all I can find is either for Bedrock, or involves extensive plugins. Is there a way to do this in vanilla? If not, then I don't mind using plugins/mods as long as it's not overly complicated. I'd also like to be able to execute the command via a python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to link 2 different servers together?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266872/is-it-possible-to-link-2-different-servers-together)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this in Vanilla. Separate servers are separate. From all I've heard about these mods, they're all pretty complicated, because you need to trick a client into doing this, which isn't normally made to support it. And both servers needs to know what is going on and some program needs to handle the transition between them.

I would recommend just telling people to switch servers or to to try to implement everything with one server, whatever you're trying to do. Maybe asking how to do that would be a better question (meaning: one that gives you a more helpful answer).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you cannot do this with just vanilla servers.

The probably best known solution to do this is a [Bungeecord](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/) setup. Bungeecord is **not a minecraft server**, but acts as a sort of reverse proxy for your players. They will connect to the bungee server, which will then forward them to the respective running server. There are some alternatives like [Waterfall from the PaperMC project](https://github.com/PaperMC/Waterfall).

Afaik this setup requires you to use spigot/bukkit/paper servers, but there again are options to add plugins to this and make it compatible with vanilla. A quick search points to [Vanillacord](https://github.com/Thinkofname/vanillacord) and [its updates](https://github.com/ME1312/VanillaCord/tree/master/src/main/java/uk/co/thinkofdeath/vanillacord).